# PHP Groupings and LOOPS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How would I group this by skill and echo all the photo's for each skill.

```
SELECT skills.teacher, skills.student, skills.skill, profile.photo
FROM skills
INNER JOIN profile ON skills.student = profile.username
WHERE teacher =  'teach1'

teacher | student  | skill  | photo
------- | -------- | ------ | ------------
teach1  | student1 | skill1 | student1.jpg
teach1  | student2 | skill1 | student2.jpg
teach1  | student3 | skill2 | student3.jpg
teach1  | student3 | skill1 | student3.jpg
teach1  | student4 | skill3 | student4.jpg
teach1  | student1 | skill2 | student1.jpg
```

I stress this is an example. I do not actually know the names of the "skill" as they are created by the students. I don't know how many skills will be listed in all. I don't know what users will add what skills to what teachers.

I have tried while loops and foreach loops. I just can't figure out how to group this and what type of loop to use...

I need my end result to allow me to echo.

```
<div>skill1 
 <img src="student1.jpg">
 <img src="student2.jpg">
 <img src="student3.jpg">
 ...
 ...
 ...
</div>

<div>skill2
 <img src="student1.jpg">
 <img src="student3.jpg">
 ...
 ...
 ...
</div>

 <div>skill3
 <img src="student4.jpg">
 ...
 ...
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, order by skill, so that you get them in order:

```
SELECT skills.teacher, skills.student, skills.skill, profile.photo
FROM skills
INNER JOIN profile ON skills.student = profile.username
WHERE teacher =  'teach1'
ORDER BY skills.skill
```

Assign a variable (In this case `$lastSkill`) outside of your while loop. Check if it's changed, and output things accordingly. Take a look at the example below. Your PHP code would look something similar to this:

```
$lastSkill = null;

while ( $row = fetchrow() )
{
    if ( $row['skill'] !== $lastSkill )
    {
        //Don't close a div, if it's the first row
        if ( $lastSkill !== null )
            echo '</div>';

        //We've moved onto a new row, echo it out
        echo '<div>' . $row['skill'];
        //Store the lastSkill
        $lastSkill = $row['skill'];
    }

    echo '<img src="' . $row['photo'] . '">';
}
```

Comment: took me a minute to realize fetchrow is ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) but I got it. :) Thank you so much

Comment: @Bruce You never posted your database connection/fetch code, so I had to do a bit of [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) guessing there.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT skills.teacher, skills.student, skills.skill, profile.photo
FROM skills
INNER JOIN profile ON skills.student = profile.username
WHERE teacher =  'teach1' Group by skills.skill order by skills.?

**ORDER BY WHATEVER YOU WANT PUT IN PLACE OF ?.**
```

Comment: How does this get him to his end result?

Comment: you will get the required result.  SELECT skills.teacher, skills.student, skills.skill, profile.photo
FROM skills
INNER JOIN profile ON skills.student = profile.username
WHERE teacher =  'teach1' Group by skills.skill     run this query in my sql you will get.