# PHP MySql: Loop check row value if same as previous, add something at the last item of the group

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, while-loop

Hello I need some help in grouping items. I have data like below.

```
id | area | cost
1  |   a  |   100
2  |   b  |   100
3  |   a  |   100
4  |   c  |   100
5  |   c  |   100
6  |   a  |   100
```

I want to achieve to display a table like below

```
id | area
1  |   a
3  |   a
6  |   a
```

display total (sum of all area a)

```
2  |   b
```

display total (sum of all area b)

```
4  |   c
5  |   c
```

display total (sum of all area c)

---

I can segregate all the rows order by area(asc) and arrange it by id(desc)
I am using the code below but doesnt do what I intended to do.

```
$itemdeleted = 1;
$query = $conn->prepare('
SELECT *
  FROM projectscostbreakdown 
 WHERE projectscostbreakdown_projectid=:projectsid 
    && projectscostbreakdown_deleted=:itemdeleted
 GROUP 
    BY projectscostbreakdown_areaname ASC
     , projectscostbreakdown_id DESC
');
$query->bindParam(':projectsid', $projectsid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':itemdeleted', $itemdeleted, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Then loop it

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
display id - area - cost
if (currentareavalue != previousareavalue)
display sum of all the previous costs with the same areaname
}
```

My problem is i want to display the total cost of every area at the end of the last entry of an area.
I am new to php and please bear with me.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38734270/4875631) on how to get an idea to do something similar.